# split Opportunity values by month

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-split

I have a problem with another trigger.

We have Opps with periods more than a month, usually, 6 or 12 months.
When I ran a report, it only gives me the total value of the opp for each month, how can i ran reports on specific months and only see the partial value for this specific period?

for example: Opp with period feb 2016 - jan 2017 total of 120 K€
my report period is for Q1 2016, so i want to see only 20 K€ (feb + mar 2016)

Comment: How do you track period of opp?

Comment: 2 custom date fields, contract start date and end date

Comment: Seems like you could create a formula field to divide opp amount by number of months to get a monthly amt, and sum the monthly amt, but there are some complexities there I would need to poke on it.  I have an opp record type w a similar data model so can see what I can come up with.  Are the dates always whole months, IE feb 01 2016 - Jan 31 2017?

Comment: Hi Gorav, no, unfortunately not, its very different, like Jan 04 2016 - Jan 03 2017 or Jan 01 2016 - Jan 31 2016

Comment: In that case what counts as a month?  Would a partial month count as a month?  If they started Jan 15 would you want to see 5 VS 10

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can achieve this by dropping the Close Date(or any other date you use) into the report and group the Close date - by Calender Quater and Summing the Amount field.or you can use Close date (or any other date you use) to filter on the report to show only Q1 Opportunities
[image]

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Kiran, this standard functionality is not what i am looking for, as this will show the total opp amount in the month of closing date but not drilled down to each month of the duration.

Comment: @RalfWittenberger Can you look at the image that i have attached to the answer and see whether this is what you are looking for

Comment: Hey Kiran, thx for your answer, but this is not, what i need, this will only show the opportunity amount once for the closing month. I have in my opportunities 2 date fields, start contract and end contract, and i want to have the opp amount splitted to months for each of the period.

Comment: @RalfWittenberger  have you tried using an Joined report?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the product schedules?  I looked into it, as we sell in a subscription model.  In the end, we decided not to use it as once the revenue schedule is created you have to edit it again if you change the close date (I and my sales guys found this kind of annoying), but have a look in a sandbox and see if that will work for you.  It does give you the revenue broken out per month, but the upfront work might not be worth it.